# curdate interval for a int field?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select records from the last 3 years...

the following use to work when the table column type 'released_year' was a date

```
$query = 'SELECT
             album.album_id,
             album.title,
             album.released_year,
      FROM album
      WHERE  album.released_year >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 YEAR )
      ORDER BY album.released_year DESC, album.title';
```

but the table column type change and it's now a type smallint to handle only the 4 digits of a year.

How do i select records from the last 3 years now?

Answer (score 3):

...   album.released_year >= year(CURDATE()) -3 ...

ugly as you're not using real dates, but it will work for a while

Comment: for some reason '-3' returns records from 2009 to 2012.. that's 4 years... so i've changed it to '-2'.. thanks